# ASP.NET MVC request processing sequence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sequence-diagram

Is there a definitve guide/reference on exactly *what methods* and in *what sequence* are invoked while processing a request in an ASP.NET MVC pipeline? Much like a sequence diagram, I guess.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/entrypage/be-ahead-of-the-game-poster1 (link to a zipped pdf poster)

Comment: I removed the "event" stuff to avoid answers that merely point out that MVC is not WebForms.

Comment: @Stefanvds, really?  I think desiring a better understanding of when and how things happen in MVC does mean that the person should not be using MVC.

Comment: @mark123 - that's a nice diagram.

Comment: @mark123 Thanks, but no. For one, it does not mention action filters. Moreover, it doesn't clarify what exact methods are invoked on every step.

Comment: anton, it think it is better to specify your questions. i can answer the action filter stuff.

Comment: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781 - the best documentation. The source code itself. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Up to date ASP.Net MVC 3 Request-Handling Pipeline Diagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541732/up-to-date-asp-net-mvc-3-request-handling-pipeline-diagram)

Answer (score 3):

This is one of my favorite links to print out and give to MVC learners:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/

Comment: Thanks, but that's way too old - it's even pre-CTP1 of ASP.NET MVC 1.0.