# Up to date ASP.Net MVC 3 Request-Handling Pipeline Diagram?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone point me to an up-to date diagram of the ASP.Net MVC 3 request handling pipeline?

I've got an older version (MVC v1, v2), but it's no longer accurate, given the introduction of IControllerActivator in MVC3 (and possibly other framework changes).

Comment: Its very, very old but really detailed: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/blogfiles/2007/ASPNET-MVC-Pipeline/ASP.NET%20MVC%20Pipeline.jpg

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC : Request-Handling Pipeline Poster](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/10/08/aspnet-mvc-learning-resource-request-handling-pipeline-poster/)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is somewhat late for an answer but this could help someone (definitely helped me)

[ASP.NET MVC Pipeline](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/file.ashx?file=6068)

Taken from this great article: [An Introduction to ASP.NET MVC Extensibility](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1358)

Comment: Great reference. Have a badge! (+10)

Comment: We now have [this document](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) from the ASP .Net site that is up to date with MVC 5.

Answer (score 6):

This is a Request-handling Pipeline for ASP.NET MVC 2: http://ajaxus.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/asp_net_mvc_poster.pdf (or see page 228, Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 by Steven Sanderson).
The request pipeline is (maybe) not change in V3, but MVC 3 is extend some point to allow injection in every node of pipeline.

Example:
- At node: Controller factory:
+ ControllerBuilder create an instance of IControllerFactory (ex: the default factory)
+ factory implement Create() of IControllerFactory by:
++ Using an instance of IControllerActivation (activation)
++ Call activation.Create() of IControllerActivation to get instance of controller

So, **IControllerActivation** is work in **DefaultControllerFactory**. We can still use **DefaultControllerFactory** and replace **IControllerActivation**, or replace the **DefaultControllerFactory** with custom **IControllerFactory** (with or without use **IControllerActivation**)

Comment: Thanks, langtu, but I already have that diagram.  I'm looking for one specific to MVC 3