# Different default routes for different roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a different default route for a different user role?

e.g.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Admin", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "totalrewardstatement", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Have the default route above for normal users but use the admin one if an admin user logs in?

Comment: I think looking at the lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC request might help you understand this problem better.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541732/up-to-date-asp-net-mvc-3-request-handling-pipeline-diagram

Comment: similar  to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181284/mvc-role-based-routing

Answer (score 3):

Role based routing is not supported in MVC. What you do is have default controller which checks for the roles and redirect to that controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (User.IsInRole("Supervisor"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "InvitationS");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1994888.aspx?role+based+routing+asp+net+mvc](http://forums.asp.net/t/1994888.aspx?role%20based%20routing%20asp%20net%20mvc)

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom ***RouteConstraint*** did the trick for me on mvc 5.

```
    public class RoleConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match
            (
                HttpContextBase httpContext,
                Route route,
                string parameterName,
                RouteValueDictionary values,
                RouteDirection routeDirection
            )
        {
            return httpContext.User.IsInRole(parameterName) ;
        }
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Reader_Home",
        url: "",
        defaults: new { controller = "Reader", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { reader_role = new RoleConstraint() }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Author_Home",
        url: "",
        defaults: new { controller = "Publication", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { author_role = new RoleConstraint() }
    );
```

I'm using the parameterName (author_role and reader_role) as the role name to check for simplification.

Comment: Any idea is it's possible to verify if the destination controller / action requires authentication? For example, I have some controllers and actions that AllowAnonymous